# Что делает параметр scope в хелпере form_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Не могу разобраться - что делает параметр `scope` в хелпере `form_with`? Вот пример из документации

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, local: true do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из документации же:

> :scope - The scope to prefix input field names with and thereby how the submitted parameters are grouped in controllers.

То есть, этот параметр задает префикс для названий инпутов, и по нему они группируются при передаче в контроллер. Например, вот такая форма

```
<%= form_with scope: :post, url: posts_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

сгенерирует вот такой html

```
<form action="/posts" method="post" data-remote="true">
  <input type="text" name="post[title]">
</form>
```

Обратите внимание на `name="post[title]"`, а не просто `name="title"`. В результате, в контроллер прилетит `post: { title: 'Some title' }` - все параметры формы будут лежать под ключом `post`